# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Tags: javascript, html, browser, syntax

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;     line 90

This would be line 90: `$('area').on('click', function() ;`

Content type is set to charset=UTF-8.

```
  <script>
       $(document).ready(function(e) {
$('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
$('area').on('click', function() ;
      });
   </script>
```

Comment: As the error **clearly** states, your code makes no sense.

Comment: Console is trying to help you by specifying the error.

Comment: The error points right to the line. Do you really think `function() ;}` is valid?

Comment: the code works, thats the thing just wanna remove the error.

Comment: @Jim wrong, the code does not work because it cannot be parsed! Check out my answer that explains how to do it!

Answer (score 3):

You should have been able to work this out for yourself by reading the error.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
            $('area').on(function(){

            });  
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Your snippet still have an error, you're not closing the `.ready` call, add another `});` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing several tokens `{,},)`. It should be:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
     $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
     $('area').on('click', function() {
                //Code here
     }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <script>
       $(document).ready(function(e) {
          $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
          $('area').on('click', function() {
            // your code here...
          });
      });
   </script>
```

Comment: onclick is wrong see my solution

Comment: @Naveen sorry, I've editted it too right now.

Comment: OK fine... once see my solution....

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo on the fourth line of your code:

```
$('area').on('click', function() ; // <- the semicolon has nothing to do here
      });
```

should be:

```
$('area').on('click', function() {
});
```

You also need to end the `.ready` call:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
    $('area').on('click', function() {
      // do something when the <area> element is clicked
    }); // end of the .on call
}); // end of the .ready call
</script>
```

Comment: thank you all for the fast help!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is right, there is an unexpected ; right there...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
    $('area').on('click', function(){

    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(e) {
      $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
      $('area').on('click', function() {
         //code here
      });
   });
</script>
```

Change your code from

```
$('area').on('click', function() ;
  //code
});
```

to

```
$('area').on('click', function(){
  //code
});
```